# How will the packages be upgraded when changing the repository?

Tags: debian, apt

I want install Debian 9, but repository don't have php7.1. If I will install PHP7.1 from repository deb.sury.org  now and when php7.1 come to official repository later, what will Debian do in situation, when package was installed from non-official repository, but upgrade from official repository? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the package name will be exactly same, automatic upgrade will select the biggest version, but you could always choose exact version You want.

If the pacage name is different and when the package appears in official repository You can uninstall unofficial one, and install official package.